# exists argument is not a hash or array element, why?

Tags: perl

I'm typing a perl script and the output gaves me an error "exists argument is not a HASH or ARRAY element"

My code is:

```
if (exists (${\%{$port}}{Implementation}[0]{azgLongName}) or exists (${\%{$port}}{Implementation}[0]{azgShortName} or exists (${\%{$port}}{Implementation}[0]{interpretation}))
     {
        delete @{${\%{$port}}{Implementation}}[0]->{azgLongName};
        delete @{${\%{$port}}{Implementation}}[0]->{azgShortName};
        delete @{${\%{$port}}{Implementation}}[0]->{interpretation};
     }
```

How come is this an error? (also using template toolkit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your parens are misplaced. You have `exists( ... or exists( ... ) )`.

Fixed and cleaned up (`\%{$port}`⇒`$port`, `${…}{…}`⇒`…->{…}`):

```perl
if (
   (  exists( $port->{ Implementation }[ 0 ]{ azgLongName    } )
   || exists( $port->{ Implementation }[ 0 ]{ azgShortName   } )
   || exists( $port->{ Implementation }[ 0 ]{ interpretation } )
   )
) {
   delete $port->{ Implementation }[ 0 ]{ azgLongName    };
   delete $port->{ Implementation }[ 0 ]{ azgShortName   };
   delete $port->{ Implementation }[ 0 ]{ interpretation };
}
```

Simplified (Factored out common part):

```perl
my $imp0 = $port->{ Implementation }[ 0 ];

if (
   (  exists( $imp0->{ azgLongName    } )
   || exists( $imp0->{ azgShortName   } )
   || exists( $imp0->{ interpretation } )
   )
) {
   delete $imp0->{ azgLongName    };
   delete $imp0->{ azgShortName   };
   delete $imp0->{ interpretation };
}
```

Simplified (No need to check for existence before deleting):

```perl
my $imp0 = $port->{ Implementation }[ 0 ];

delete $imp0->{ azgLongName    };
delete $imp0->{ azgShortName   };
delete $imp0->{ interpretation };
```

Simplified (We can delete a slice instead of deleting three elements individually):

```perl
my $imp0 = $port->{ Implementation }[ 0 ];

delete $imp0->@{qw( azgLongName azgShortName interpretation )};
```